# derailleur P-screw/B-screw does absolutely nothing

Tags: derailleur, shimano, adjustment, derailleur-rear, adjustment-screw

I know dérailleur adjustments are frustrating, but this is the 4th day i'm working on this... i stop working just before the rage kicks in and leave everything to continue another day :)

The problem is: on the lowest (smallest) gear on front, the guide(?) gear from the dérailleur will grind on half the low (larger) gears on back. on the middle front gear (have 3) only the lowest (larger) gear on back grinds.

This is what I have:
[image: Shimano RD-MT60, Deore]
http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=3f73f16c-1a7e-46c5-ab73-f21755e71b08&Enum=108

That is not my picture, but the distance from the guide gear to the lowest rear gear is almost the same. it makes a wicked noise on pedaling.

The steps I did last, was to start all over again.

1. moved index to highest (small) gear. i.e. less pull on cable.
2. removed cable from derailleur.
3. left P-screw half inserted.
4. loosened H-screw (bottom) until it stopped moving outward.
5. screwed in H-screw until it aligned with highest (small) cog.
6. pulled the derailleur arm with one hand down and into the wheel
7. adjusted the L-screw (top) until arm stopped moving to the wheel
8. screwed in L-screw until arm was aligned with Lowest (big) cog.
9. let go of arm
10. adjust cable fine tune to be almost fully inserted in thread
11. secured cable on derailleur with almost no pull.
12. pulled cable to remove slack.
13. re-tightened cable again with almost no pull.
14. tested index shifting with front on middle gear.
15. adjusted fine cable pull screw for tight second and penultimate gear shifts.
16. noticed grind on lowest gear (large).
17. screwed in P-screw. nothing changed. rage.
18. tried with front derraileur on highest (small) gear. grinding now on half the low gears on back. more rage.

What am i doing wrong here? What else can control the proximity of the guide pulley/gear and the low gears other than the P-screw?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right derailer and lever set for your rear cluster?

Comment: (Ignoring the highest and lowest cogs, does one click of the lever move the derailer exactly one cog?)

Comment: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailler-adjustments-derailleur

Comment: @DanielRHicks this is the original that shipped with the bike. It is working on a 5sp freewheel, that is also original. Later years that model was used even with a 6sp with the lower one with 2 more teeth. i'm sure it is something dumb i'm doing. or maybe 20+yrs are too much for the components... though i cleaned it up and lubed last year, this is the first time i'm fine tunning it. Edit, yes i read the parktool guide and others. i'm 4days into this :( with lots of reading in between. the B-Screw/P-screw does zero. nada. nothing.

Comment: That screw has essentially nothing to do with making the derailer center over the cogs -- it's purely to adjust tension in the chain, and, to a degree, adjust how far the jockey wheel stands away from the cog.

Comment: (If you removed/disassembled the cluster, make sure you didn't do something there to throw the cluster in or out relative to where it was originally.)

Comment: You could always take it to your LBS, hand the guy 10 bucks or whatever and let him set it up for you.

Comment: @DanielRHicks it is aligned perfectly, it is just eh distance from the guide to the freewheel lowest gears. And you are probably right... maybe i screwed up when opening it... will probably open it again and go over all the steps. all the painfully boring steps of reassembly a rear derailleur :( ...first i will make sense of http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ca-g.html#capacity and make double sure the part is being used in the right place as you mentioned on the 1st comment

Comment: @Batman after 4 days, you pass that line where it is now too embarrassing to not fix it and too shameful to look for help.

Comment: What did you open up?  What did you disassemble?

Comment: "on the high (smallest) gear on front" I assume it's the low gear, not high?

Comment: @gcb he's speaking of front gears -> small lower, and high larger.

Comment: @Alexander sorry, saw the mistake now. fixed it on the question. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRHicks i opened the whole thing, removed all springs, scrubbed a little superficial rust layer from the inner parts and removed the clogged up old grease, packed everything back with parktool grease that was within shimano spec. THe main spring that is what the P/B-screw affect has no way to be put in wrong, i guess...

Comment: When you say "noticed grind", what do you mean?

Comment: @DanielRHicks the guide gear on the derailleur arm grinding on the low gear of the freehweel. almost like the picture. it makes a loud clicking noise that i don't hear on higher gears.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how that's even possible.  The chain sits between the jockey wheel and the sprocket and they move in synchrony, so there should be no "grinding", even if they touch.  But normally they should maintain about a half-inch separation from chain tension alone, unless the sprocket is too large for the derailer.

Comment: @DanielRHicks they run with only the chain links separating them. The noise cames from the chain axis passing between. It is very possible, hence the Raison d'être of the B/P-Screw. It is there just to adjust the guide being closer to the gear but not touching. Also, i am starting to think it does not matter much. I will only have low gear front and rear when i'm pedaling as slow as possible anyway... don't think anything bad will happen if i leave as is....

Comment: @DanielRHicks see the second paragraph here http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailler-adjustments-derailleur " If the pulley is rubbing against this cog, tighten the B-screw to increase upper pivot spring tension, which pulls the pulley back and away from the cog" what happens in my case, is, no matter what i do with the B-screw, the distance from the pulley and lowest cog remains the same. the arm never moves when i change the B-screw.

Comment: If you look at the Park Tool page you linked, in the pictures where it says "Higher tension setting" and "Lower tension setting", is the end of your B-screw seated on a ridge of the derailleur hanger like theirs is? Sometimes the screw can miss that ridge, or the ridge gets rounded or sheared off. Also, just validating that: (a) I've had this problem and (b) yes, the B-screw is the thing that fixes it. Also, stay cool. Hard to fix stuff while raging :^)

Comment: @joseph_morris ok, came back at this, again :) last time i adjusted the H and L screws as best as I could. and really, the cogs only grind now when using lowest in front and lowest in back. so i was avoiding this [in the 2 times i was able to ride since then :(] and well, the b-screw is still screwing me. everything seems perfect, but it does nothing. it sits in the correct place on the frame just fine. I think i will have to open the derailleur... but i think for the trouble, i might get a new one... well, i will just avoid the climbs for now :)

Answer (score 2):

If the derailleur is old, the internal spring which is meant to swing the derailleur out away from the cassette might be worn to the point that it is no longer able to keep the derailleur far enough out. You might be able to replace the b limit screw with a longer screw in order to make it work.

Comment: very good point! I did not check the spring strenght when i renewd the derailleur. I am using it as is and set it up so that it only grinds in the very lowest combinations (which i rarely use for my comute).. but as soon as i have to open it up again for lube/mud removal, i will surelly check it up and update here if that was the case.